Positive distance weighting
I have an overdetermined linear system of equations that's solved with least squares. I'd like to weight the equations to penalize a bunch of inputs clumped up together.
Ideally if two (or more) inputs are the same I'd have them both weighted down as they were a single point, while evenly spaced points had the same maximal weight.
Any ideas where should I look? I don't even know which branch of maths I should be looking at.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization

What does "weighted down as they were a single point" and "maximal weight" mean?  What does "penalize a bunch of inputs clumped up together"?

Weighted least squares is a standard solution.  Standard statistical software implements various forms of weights, so the only work you have to do is to create a variable containing the desired weights.  Stata implements four kinds of weights, of which it seems you want "frequency weights:" see https://www.reed.edu/psychology/stata/gs/tutorials/weights.html. // But why do you reference "distance" in your title?  Your question as stated has nothing to do with distance weighting.  That can be done in certain specialized ways, such as interpolating data, leaving us to wonder what you really mean.

If I get it right in Weighted Least Squares the weight matrix is from the variance-covariance matrix. I don't have that sort of information. Instead I'd like to create weights based on how close the independent variables of the input are.
I have systematic errors in my input that are unknown but not random. If I have a significant portion of inputs close together (close in independent variables) my solution will be effected by a higher contribution of the value of systematic error around where the inputs are "clumped" together. This is why I'm trying to incentivize a nice even spread.

E.g. my independent variables for 3 inputs are x1=1 x2=2 x3=100. I'd like y1 and y2 to be weighted by about 0.5 considering how close x1 is to x2 vs. how far x3 is.
I just don't know if there's any universally used metric that can be used to calculate the weights to achieve this effect.
I suspect that the first comment by Kakashi might have to actually do with what I want, but starting from that point it's a deep rabbit hole and I'm missing prerequisites so I couldn't process it yet.
